# Conditionally bind a directive in vue js

Tags: vue.js, bind, directive

I would like to conditionally bind the vue directive v-dragscroll. Can someone please tell me if this is possible in vue js?

Comment: No, use two elements with `v-if` and `v-else`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that first but it gave me some problems. Now I got it working

Answer (score 0):

We can use template tag to achieve this in template as below, say if we want to add v-dragscroll to any div element

Template option

[image: 1]

If you are using render then it is even more easy to achieve

Render option

[image: 2]